# Добиться сопоставления числа и атома

Tags: логика, prolog

Преподаватель попросил фрагмент программы, чтобы в итоге произошло сопоставление атома и числа. Если, например, ввести такую:

```
    PREDICATES
    праздник(symbol,integer,integer)
    др(symbol,integer,integer)

    CLAUSES
    др(май,24,1996).
    праздник(Месяц,Число,Год):-др(Месяц,Число,Год).

    GOAL
    праздник(май,двадцать_четыре,1996).
```

то будет естественно ошибка, так как типы не совпадают. Преподаватель мне сказал, что можно как-то это ограничение обойти и чтобы в итоге сопоставление произошло. Может кто-нибудь знает как этого добиться ?

Answer (score 0):

В разделе domains (он обычно идет первым) нужно ввести новый тип
symint=integer;symbol

далее в разделе predicates в предикатах праздник и др во втором аргументе указать вместо integer symint

др(symbol,symint,integer)

Должно помочь.